# Java - use of volatile only makes sense in multiprocessor systems?

Tags: java, multithreading, operating-system, multiprocessing, volatile

Use of volatile only makes sense in multiprocessor systems. is this wrong?

i'm trying to learn about thread programming, so if you know any good articles/pdfs ... i like stuff that mentions a bit about how the operating system works as well not just the language's syntax.

Comment: Not an answer, but the page 4 of (this article)[http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-02-2001/jw-0209-double.html?page=1] explains how to _not_ use volatile and why. Not obvious at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

volatile is used to ensure all thread see the same copy of the data. If there is only one thread reading/writing to a field, it doesn't need to be volatile. It will work just fine, just be a bit slower.

In Java you don't have much visibility as to the processor architecture, generally you talk in terms of threads and multi-threading.

I suggest Java Concurrency in Practice, it good whatever your level of knowledge, http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com/

The whole point of using Java is you don't need to know most of the details of how threads work etc.  If you learn lots of stuff you don't use you are likely to forget it. ;)

Comment: JCiP is a must have and must read book when you are serious about writing multithreaded programs. +1

Answer (score 11):

No. Volatile can be used in *multi-threaded* applications. These may or may not run on more than one processor.

Answer (score 1):

Volatile makes sense in a multithreaded programm, running these threads on a single processor or multiple processors does not make a difference. The volatile keyword is used to tell the JVM (and the Java Memory Model it uses) that it should not re-order or cache the value of a variable with this keyword. This guarantees that Threads using a volatile variable will never see a stale version of that variable.

See [this](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#volatile) link on the Java Memory Model in general for more details. Or [this](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#volatile) one for information about Volatile.

Answer (score 1):

No. Volatile is used to support concurrency. In certain circumstances, it can be used instead of synchronization.

This [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20100120092155/http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp06197.html) by Brian Goetz really helped me understand `volatile`. It has several examples of the use of `volatile`, and it explains under what conditions it can be used.