# Volatile keyword in multicore vs single processor?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, volatile

I have heard many people saying that volatile keyword makes more sense in multicore processor
than single core processor but don't know the reason. I tried to google but did not help in
this aspect. Any reason for it?

As per my understanding volatile keyword should have equal importance whether it is multicore vs single processor.
Reason is with volatile , its guaranteed that value will be updated in main memory (heap) instead of keeping
it in thread local memory(stack) which can be seen by all threads. So whether its multicore or single processor,
how does it makes difference?

Comment: Your senior is wrong, I'm afraid; he fails to account for TLS (Thread Local Storage) which even some single-core CPUs have

Comment: Multithreading might be more common in multicore systems, but it is defeinitely used in single processor systems too. So you are correct, `volatile` is important to consider in both cases.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java - use of volatile only makes sense in multiprocessor systems?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606895/java-use-of-volatile-only-makes-sense-in-multiprocessor-systems)

Comment: You could say, forgetting a necessary `volatile` is more likely to break on SMP machines but there’s no point in speculating about the likeliness of breaking when writing software. And you are right, reordering and deferred read/writes are relevant on single-CPU/Core systems as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "sense of volatile" has nothing to do with the number of cores. The JVM hides the underlying architecture. Not to mention that volatile is a language keyword, so it should behave the same on every architecture.

You described what volatile does, and it is correct. The **architecture of the application** that could require the usage of volatile, nothing else.

If you are interested, here is a great post related to volatile, and the basic concepts of the memory model used in Java.

http://jeremymanson.blogspot.hu/2008/11/what-volatile-means-in-java.html

Answer (score 3):

First of all, "volatile" tries to reduce visibility problems that might occur across different threads (think of the local variables/copies of the shared variables in each thread scope). However, the level of parallelisation is more and easier to visualise when you have multiple CPU cores (caches, registers). IMO, that's why it makes more sense in multi-core architectures. Nevertheless, that visibility issue may even arise when you have a single-core, multiple threads and two of them happens to read the same variable value one after another before the other updates it. In either case, volatile's gonna work the same way regardless of having a single or multi core architecture.

The key is understanding your volatile variables on the CPU cache or registers will be written back to main memory with an IMMEDIATE write policy, so any **subsequent** reads of the same variable reads the latest updated value.

Volatile only increases the chance of having synched threads - but it's **not** guaranteed. If you've multiple threads updating the shared data volatile might not be enough alone. There're other features that you can take advantage of with the volatile concept. Please take a look [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/volatile.html).

Answer (score -3):

Your understanding is correct. `volatile` keyword makes no sense in single-**threaded** application, no matter it runs on single core or multicore CPU, because `volatile` variable guarantees changes visible to **threads**. If you don't, most likely you'll have visibility issues even on single core environment. In case of multithreaded application running in sngle- or multicore environment, there are cases when you need `volatile` variables (or other ways or synchronization/visibility guarantees).

Comment: Who said the application is single-threaded? The problem related to single/multi core architecture.

Comment: Your answer seems to consider single thread on single core and multithread on multicore but seems to skip over multithread on single core. Which is the core of this question

Answer (score -3):

As per my understanding volatile is not relevant in single core. Volatile variable updates are pushed/read from main memory which is important in a multi-core architecture where each core can have its own cache, hence an update in a particular core's cache may not be visible for other threads running on a different core.

However if you have a single core, then when you update a variable which is not volatile, if it gets updated in the core's cache without being pushed to main memory this may be fine because all the other threads run on the same core hence will see the latest value available in the cache that they all share. So you dont need a volatile there.